# Continuous line numbering in lstlisting, but separate lsttableoflistings entries?

Tags: listings, line-numbering, lstlisting

i'd like to use the `name=something,firstlinenumber=auto` function for continuous line numbering throughout a couple of subsequent listings in my document. I'd also like to have each of the listings have its own separate entry in the List of Listings. The `listings` package seems to not like that, though: If I use the same `name=something` for multiple listings, only the first one gets an entry in the List of Listings, every other one does not. If I do not use `name=something`, each listing gets it's own entry in the List of Listings, but the continuous line numbering no longer works. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left,firstnumber=auto}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\section{Contents}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=test,label=first,caption=First Listing]
this should start at line number 1
and should be the first entry in the List of Listings
\end{lstlisting}

Listing~\ref{first} shows up correctly in the List of Listings.

\begin{lstlisting}[name=test,label=second,caption=Second Listing]
this continues line numbers from the previous listing
but does not get an entry in the List of Listings
\end{lstlisting}

Listing~\ref{second} continues the line numbering, and has its own listing number
that can be referenced, but does not receive an entry in the list of Listings.

% parameter "name=test" is removed here..
\begin{lstlisting}[label=third,caption=Third Listing]
this restarts the line numbers from line 1
but does get a second entry in the List of Listings
\end{lstlisting}

Listing~\ref{third} also has its own listing number that can be referenced, and
does get an entry in the List of Listings, but does not continue line numbers.

\end{document}
```

Obviously I could manually count each listings' lines and then manually set the starting line number for each subsequent listing, but I'd prefer a more robust automatic solution. Does anyone know a way to get both behaviors, continuous line numbers AND separate List of Listings entries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this `marcro` from `Yiannis Lazarides's` cheeky answer, you can get the so-called robustness. That is with different naming, you not only continue the line numbering but also get the `listings` listed as they appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95036/continue-line-numbers-in-listings-package
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{bash}[1][]
{\lstset{language=C}\lstset{%
        numbers=left,
        #1
}}
{}


%
%%% Always I forget this so I created some aliases
\def\ContinueLineNumber{\lstset{firstnumber=last}}
\def\StartLineAt#1{\lstset{firstnumber=#1}}
\let\numberLineAt\StartLineAt


\begin{document}

    \lstlistoflistings
    \ContinueLineNumber
    \section{Contents}

    \begin{bash}[name=test,label=first,caption=First Listing]
    this should start at line number 1
    and should be the first entry in the List of Listings
    \end{bash}

    Listing~\ref{first} shows up correctly in the List of Listings.

    \begin{bash}[name=test5,label=second,caption=Second Listing]
    this continues line numbers from the previous listing
    but does not get an entry in the List of Listings
    \end{bash}

No more problems :)

    % parameter "name=test" is removed here..
    \begin{bash}[name=test77, label=third,caption=Third Listing]
    this no more restarts the line numbers from line 1
    but does continue in the List of Listings
    \end{bash}

    The macro does the job.
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

Comment: Ohh I see. I had seen this macro and tried using it, but it didn't work because I used it wrong. Now I see how it's supposed to be used, and it indeed does the job. Thanks!